# Personal information online (Instagram) no way to control

Tags: social-media

I'm trying to work out the legal routes for reclaiming control of personal information online.

Backstory: I have had an Instagram account for a long time. Then one day (a few years ago) I couldn't log in. I was told to verify my email but, inside the same email, there was a link that removed the email from the account entirely - I accidentally clicked this instead.

So now my account was locked (hacked) and my email was removed from the account. I reached out to Instagram support (back then they had an email address) and they asked me to prove my identity by showing my face next to my passport photo page. I did this and waited. Eventually I received a response saying that I failed to prove my identity. This is the last I've heard from them.

Now I have a page online, with my personal information and photos and I have absolutely no way of controlling this.

Do I have a right to control this information? If so what kind of legal person do I need to contact?

Comment: In what country are you located? It may make a difference.

Comment: Located in the UK